# How to get records of two different models from solr in django

Tags: python, django, solr

I have two models and i created indexes for two separate models in search_indexes.py file. I created schema.xml file using the command build_solr_schema. I have mentioned index for two models below

```
class AIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
   text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
   a = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='a',null=True)
   b = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='b',null=True)
   c = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='c',null=True)

   def get_model(self):
       return A
   def index_queryset(self,using=None):
       return get_model().objects.all()

class BIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
   text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
   d = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='d',null=True)
   e = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='e',null=True)
   f = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='f',null=True)

   def get_model(self):
       return B
   def index_queryset(self,using=None):
       return get_model().objects.all()
```

I have created two templates A_text.txt and B_text.txt file

A_text.txt:

```
{{object.a}}
{{object.b}}
{{object.c}}
```

B_text.txt:

```
{{object.d}}
{{object.e}}
{{object.f}}
```

The problem is i can able to get records A only and displayed perfectly in A Screen. Am not able to get B records